# Windows Store App - Update hooks and trigger

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, desktop-bridge

(somehwat related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672689/updating-my-windows-store-app) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935684/programmatically-check-windows-store-app-update))

*tl;dr:* Are there some kind of *update hooks* for desktop-bridge converted apps distributed via the Windows Store? How can I trigger an app update from a converted app?

---

I use the Windows Store to distribute my electron-powered application. I wonder if there's any way to tell whether the app was updated recently or not?

There's two and a half issues I have:

1) I store settings in `AppData\Roaming` which seems to be *virtualized* for store apps. Sadly, it seems like the whole directory was cleared when I pulled the app update from the store and thus all the user settings were lost. Is there any way to **keep the AppData** on app updates?

2) How can I **trigger** an app **update** from within the **converted app**? For what I understood the store won't auto-update apps (not even if it's marked as *[mandatory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/self-install-package-updates)*). Having to fire up VS and writing an exe that uses some store API to update the app seems like overkill. Is there any *easier* solution?

2½) How do I know if my app was updated? I thought about storing the app version in the settings and comapring that with the running version on app start. But due to my issue *1)* that's not working.

Thanks in advance.

---

Feel free to post more answers. The accepted answer, albeit being correct and pointing the right direction, still feels cumbersome. In an ideal world there would be a drop-in solution that you'd just `npm i`. So be encouraged to find/build simpler solutions. (Many thanks to the <del>John</del> Stephan Wick whatsoever!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get notified when an update has been deployed for your UWP or DesktopBridge app, you can implement an UpdateTask:
[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-a-background-task-during-updatetask) / [sample code](https://stefanwick.com/2017/05/26/uwp-calling-office-interop-apis/)

You can also check at runtime what is the version of your package:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.packageversion

Your app will get updates automatically, but we won't update it while the user is running your app. If the app process keeps running, we will eventually force update it, but only when the screen is locked. You can also check from your code if an update is available and take action accordingly:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appinstaller/2016/11/11/developer-controlled-app-updates/

Your appdata should persist across app updates. If that's not what you are seeing, please post a separate dedicated question about this with repro details and we will follow up.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know of any existing electron app that uses those extension api bindings? I guess I'll need to see some code, especially how to build & bundle such extensions. Can I use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nodert-win10/windows.applicationmodel ?

Comment: The closest I have seen is this one: https://github.com/felixrieseberg/electron-uwp-background